# SwiftUI remove data into a structured array via a button in a ForEach

Tags: arrays, swiftui, foreach, structure

I'm trying to remove a line in my structured array when user click on the delete button. But as I use a foreach to load all my array lines into a specific subview I don't know how to pass the index of the ForEach into my subview to delete my line...

My code is like this,

```
ScrollView{
                VStack {
                    ForEach(planeLibrary.testPlane){plane in
                        ZStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16, style: .continuous)
                                .fill(Color.white)
                                .shadow(color: Color(Color.RGBColorSpace.sRGB, white: 0, opacity: 0.2), radius: 4)
                            
                            PlaneCellView(plane: plane, planeLibrary: planeLibrary, line: ???)
                        }
                    }
                }.padding(.horizontal, 16)
            }
```

And my PlaneCellView :

```
@State var plane: Plane
@ObservedObject var planeLibrary: PlaneLibrary
var line: Int
var body: some View {
//...
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(plane.planeImat)
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                Text(plane.planeType)
                HStack{
                    Text(plane.isSe ? "SE" : "ME")
                    Text(plane.isNight ? "-  Night" : "")
                    Text(plane.isIfr ? "-  IFR" : "")
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            Button {
               // HERE I don't know how to delete my array line ...
               planeLibrary.testPlane.remove(at: line) 
            } label: {
                 Image(systemName: "trash.circle")
                       .foregroundColor(.red)
                       .font(.system(size: 30))
            }
//...
}
```

My Plane library :

```
struct Plane: Identifiable{
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    let planeImat: String
    let planeType: String
    let isSe: Bool
    let isIfr: Bool
    let isNight: Bool
    let autoID: String
    
    init (planeImat: String, planeType: String, isSe: Bool, isIfr: Bool, isNight: Bool, autoID: String){
        self.planeType = planeType
        self.planeImat = planeImat
        self.isSe = isSe
        self.isIfr = isIfr
        self.isNight = isNight
        self.autoID = autoID
    }
    
    init(config: NewPlaneConfig){
        self.planeImat = config.imat
        self.planeType = config.type
        self.isSe = config.isSe
        self.isIfr = config.isIfr
        self.isNight = config.isNight
        self.autoID = config.autoID
    }
}
```

I've already try to add `id: \.self` as I was able to find on this forum but without any success.

Comment: Don't try to use a `line` -- instead, use the `id` and `remove(where:)`

Comment: I see but how could I get the ´id ´ ?

Comment: `plane.id` gives you the ID. By the way, it shouldn't be `@State` unless you're going to mutate it

Comment: There is no such construct as "`foreach`". We have `forEach` and `ForEach`. Please edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't actually included PlaneLibrary, so I will assume that planeLibrary.testPlane is an array of Plane structs.

There are many ways of solving this, including changing testPlane to be a Dictionary of Plane structs (indexed by id), or if order is important, in an OrderedDictionary (add the `swift-collections` [package](https://www.swift.org/blog/swift-collections/) to your project and `import OrderedCollections` in the file where it is used). You could use `testPlane.removeValue(at: id)` to remove the plane from either type of dictionary.

If you keep it as an array, but your array might be large and you're worried about run-time efficiency, the best thing to do is to change your ForEach to include the index of the planes in the loop.

It would look something like this:

```
ForEach(Array(planeLibrary.testPlane.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { index, plane in
    // In this code you can use either plane, or index.
    ...
    // UI code
    Text(plane.autoID)
    ...
    { // remove closure
         planeLibrary.testPlane.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

But if the array is of reasonable size, you could keep it as it is now and use `testPlane.remove(where:)` to find it by `id` at the time of deletion. The code for this is much simpler and easier to read and understand, so it should probably be your first choice. Optimise for large lists later, if you need.

Comment: Using `offset` is not a good idea in a `ForEach` -- it tells SwiftUI that any element at that `offset` the same as any other item at that offset -- as soon as an item gets removed, it loses identity. Instead, use the actual ID of the `plane` -- ie the `id` of the `element`

Comment: Oh, you're right. Thanks jnpdx. This trick is only good for loops where the data won't change, and is generally not a good idea for swiftUI where the idea of consistent identity is very important. I will revise my answer.

Comment: Oh I see and when using `element` for the `id` I need to put my Plane structure as `Hashable` I need to upgrade my skills with the `foreach`..

Comment: OK. I've revised it to use `\.element.id` for the ID. That should give a consistent ID. Incidentally, I would have just used the UUID struct for id, rather than extracting the string. Extracting the string from the struct is trivial if you actually need it, and the struct will be more efficient the rest of the time, I would think.

Comment: If you use `remove(where:)` and check against the ID, there's actually no reason to do `enumerated` and get the index.

Comment: Thanks again, jnpdx. I agree, and I've promoted your solution to be the right answer for most situations. You put it much more succinctly in your first comment. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the index in because that will crash the `ForEach` View. Instead, look up its index using its ID afterwards to remove it, e.g.

```
class RecipeBox: ObservableObject {
    @Published var allRecipes: [Recipe]
    @Published var collections: [String]

...

    func delete(_ recipe: Recipe) {
        delete(recipe.id)
    }
    
    func delete(_ id: Recipe.ID) {
        if let index = index(for: id) {
            allRecipes.remove(at: index)
            updateCollectionsIfNeeded()
        }
    }
...
    func index(for id: Recipe.ID) -> Int? {
        allRecipes.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id })
    }
...
```

This sample is from [Defining the source of truth using a custom binding (Apple Developer)](https://This%20sample%20is%20from%20https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui-concepts/defining-the-source-of-truth-using-a-custom-binding)